# Combine external mapping with Salesforce

Tags: integration, website-integration

I want to show an external map which reacts on user-actions in salesforce.
I already create a Visualforce-page and implemented the map via iFrame. This should work fine, i guess.

**Is there a way to show a map all the time, no matter where the user navigates? Since showing Salesforce in an iFrame doesn't work properly.**

Comment: we are going to need much more information that this in order to help.  You have shown no code and its unclear as to what the question is.

Comment: Well, I need a method which works like a single page with two iframes (one for the map, one for salesforce). The map should react on the actions the user does in Salesforce (click links, filter customers. It's important that the map is always viewable. But from what I read putting salesforce-page in an iframe isn't a solution because it wont work properly?! I dont need exact code, just a hint maybe how this could be done.

Comment: yYou don't need to use an iFrame.  Check out this post, might get you going in the right direction.  http://phollaio.tumblr.com/post/22058038379/inline-google-maps-using-visualforce

Comment: Yea, that is what I got. But you only see the map, when u are on this specific page. I need to show the map during browsing the whole salesforce environment. Maybe i could add the whole navigation to the visualforce page and open the links in a separate frame?

Comment: "Show the map during browsing the entire SF environment"  That is not going to be easy.  You would need to embed it into the sidebar, header, or each and every page.  Either way, not an easy task at all.  my advice would simply be "don't do this".  You're trying to recreate the interface